# Lens: Optic for Applicatives that can do pure and fmap?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Is there an optic that can do this for any `Applicative`:

```
-- Can be used as a Review to return into IO
(theOptic # 5) >>= print

-- Can be used as a Setter to modify items in a list
[2, 3] & theOptic .~ 6
```

The [`lens` hierarchy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) doesn't show anything that is both a `Review` and a `Setter`, so I guess it probably doesn't currently exist in lens. Is it possible to create it?

Comment: Prisms with `s = t` and `a = b` can be used as a `Review` and an arbitrary prism can be used a `Setter`, so a `Prism' s a = Prism s s a a` is probably what you're looking for?

Comment: @theindigamer If it was a `Prism` then it would allow to fetch items from an `IO`

Comment: You're looking for a weaker alternative, which precisely supports just `pure` and `fmap`?